# Using same authentication for EWS API and Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

We've been using Azure Active Directory and EWS SOAP web services successfully.

Trying to see if we can use our current authentication method to be able to also invoke Microsoft Graph (i.e. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`)

I went into Azure and added Microsoft Graph under `App Registrations -> Settings -> Required Permissions.`

This was our authorize endpoint url:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F`

I changed it to :

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com`

Is this all I had to do?  When I try to go through the oAuth 2.0 flow, the authorize request seems successful, then I'm asked to enter my credentials, and then I get an error:

> "*Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the
>   following: The client has not listed any permissions for 'Microsoft
>   Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application
>   registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check
>   the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the
>   configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to
>   fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant. Client app
>   ID: b1313958-....* "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I went into Azure and added Microsoft Graph under App Registrations ->
>   Settings -> Required Permissions.

You mentioned this as part of your question. Please check if after performing these steps for your App Registration in Azure AD, did you click on the “**Grant Permissions**” button to provide consent or not.

Looking at the error it seems Consent for Microsoft Graph related permissions isn’t done yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now

Comment: Thank you! It worked.
Related question:  can I have 2 resources in the resource parm?
I tried the following:
(https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F)

I also tried encoding & , and using colon, semicolon, and space instead, but only 1 resource gets registered, or I get an error.

Comment: @TanyaKruglikova I don't think what you're trying out with multiple resources would work.. but I'll check further. Consider accepting the answer for current question if your query is solved and open up a new question for what you're trying to do.. you'll get better responses from everyone that way.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Saigal

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787420/multiple-resources-in-authorization-request in case you have any ideas, thanks!

Comment: @TanyaKruglikova sure I'll give it a look.